# Why does the google cloud calculator say A2 machine types are not available in Toronto when the API says it exists?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

if you go on https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator and under compute engine

and fill out the number of fields:
instances: 1,
Operating System: Free,
Datacenter Location: Toronto

Now if you change the Machine Family to "Accelerator Optimised" and the  Machine Series to A2:

you will get a warning saying:

```
This instance type is not available in this region.
```

However, if you use the Google Cloud Pricing API:
https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key=API_KEY

There is an Object in the data that tells us A2 machines are available in Toronto, the object is:

```json
{
   "name":"services/6F81-5844-456A/skus/1CD3-9D89-855A",
   "skuId":"1CD3-9D89-855A",
   "description":"A2 Instance Core running in Toronto",
   "category":{
      "serviceDisplayName":"Compute Engine",
      "resourceFamily":"Compute",
      "resourceGroup":"CPU",
      "usageType":"OnDemand"
   },
   "serviceRegions":[
      "northamerica-northeast2"
   ],
   "pricingInfo":[
      {
         "summary":"",
         "pricingExpression":{
            "usageUnit":"h",
            "displayQuantity":1,
            "tieredRates":[
               {
                  "startUsageAmount":0,
                  "unitPrice":{
                     "currencyCode":"USD",
                     "units":"0",
                     "nanos":34802000
                  }
               }
            ],
            "usageUnitDescription":"hour",
            "baseUnit":"s",
            "baseUnitDescription":"second",
            "baseUnitConversionFactor":3600
         },
         "currencyConversionRate":1,
         "effectiveTime":"2022-07-18T01:31:45.922Z"
      }
   ],
   "serviceProviderName":"Google",
   "geoTaxonomy":{
      "type":"REGIONAL",
      "regions":[
         "northamerica-northeast2"
      ]
   }
}
```

Can anyone explain this or refer me to the relevant email where I can ask them?

Comment: 1) Google Cloud does not provide email addresses for support. To open a support case: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub 2) Did you go to the  Google Cloud Console GUI and select an A2 machine type for the region Toronto to confirm availability for your account?

Answer (score 1):

An SKU (Stock Keeping Unit) is an ID for billing. Just because there is an SKU, does not mean it is "in stock" (available).

To determine the availability of a machine type use the machine type API: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes

Comment: The JSON example that they give you in that documentation does not say anything about pricing which is the main thing I am trying to get @jnodorp

Comment: You can still use the billing API for that. Looks like you have to use two APIs to get what you want.